# Как получить дополнительные номера из телефонной книги в Android?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть метод, который получает главный номер контакта и имя из телефонной книги:

```
ArrayList<Contact> getAddressBook() {
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

    Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    int indexId = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID);
    int indexName = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int indexPhone = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
    Log.e("getAddressBook", );

    if (people.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setId(indexId);
            contact.setName(people.getString(indexName));
            contact.setPhone(people.getString(indexPhone));

            contacts.add(contact);

        } while (people.moveToNext());
    }
    return contacts;
}
```

**Как мне получить все дополнительные номера этого контакта?**

Answer (score 0):

Вы неверно определяете `ID` контакта. То что у вас, это `ID` записи с номером телефона.

В том наборе данных есть еще поле `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID`, по которому если сгруппировать, то и получите все номера контакта.

Answer (score 0):

В [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) есть пример как выбрать все телефоны определенного контакта

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
          new String[] {Data._ID, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, Phone.LABEL},
          Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
                  + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
          new String[] {String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);
```